# url = new java.net.URL()

Tags: java, url

`url = new java.net.URL(s)` doesn't work for me.

I have a string `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\XEPServlet\files\m1.fo` and need to make a link and give it to my formatter for output, but malformed url recieved. It seems that it doesn't make my string to url. 
I want also mention, that file `m1.fo` file is in files folder, in my webapp\product\, and I gave the full path to string like: `getServletContext().getRealPath("files/m1.fo")`. What I am doing wrong? How can I recieve the url link?

Comment: @davogotland -- it should NOT be expected to be at 100%. One of his questions has no answer, and some of them don't seem to have any clear winner for an answer. 0% is a disincentive, but don't punish someone for not having 100% or even 75%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file system path is not a URL. A URL is going to need a protocol prefix for one. To reference file system use "file:" in front of your path.

Comment: I set the path file:///C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/XEPServlet/files/m1.fo and also used this:
java.net.URL url = null;
  try{
   url = new java.net.URL(s);
  } catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e){
   errors = true;
   errorReport += "malformed url: '"+s+"'\n";
  }
  return url;

Comment: Hi. I have already started my webservice, but it formats the file with static path. Now I want to keep the same path, but take any file. My uploader gives the path like file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\m1.fo
Question is : How can I take just the name from this path- file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\m1.fo ??? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at the URL class javadoc. There are a number of methods that allow you to retrieve various parts of the URL.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get an `URL` from a file path with the `java.io.File` API :

```
String path = "C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\\webapps\\XEPServlet\\files\\m1.fo";
File f = new File(path);
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
```

Comment: You're going to need to escape those backslashes.

Comment: You don't need backslashes in filenames at all in Java. Use /.

Answer (score 1):

Try: file:///C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/XEPServlet/files/m1.fo

Answer (score 1):

It isn't preferable to write file:/// . Indeed it works on windows system,but in unix - there were problems. 
Instead of using

```
myReq.put("xml", new String []{"file:" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + 
                        getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH) + 
                        System.getProperty("file.separator") + xmlfile});
```

you can write

```
myReq.put("xml", new String [] {getUploadedFileURL (xmlfile)} );
```

, where

```
public String getUploadedFileURL(String filename) {
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(new 
            java.io.File(getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH)), 
            filename);

    return filePath.toURI().toURL().toString();
```

Comment: Ok +1 for me, but maybe the solution could be exposed more clearly, I guess.